# Putting a string input into an array and displaying them in a list

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test{                                      
  public static String[] intoArray(String input){                                       
    input = input.trim() + " ";                                     
    char word = ' ';                                        
    int num = 0;                                        

    for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++){                                      
      if (input.charAt(i) == word){                                     
        num++;                                      
      }                                     
    }                                       
    String[] array = new String[num];                                       
    for(int i=0; i< array.length; ){                                        
      for(int j=0; j < input.length(); j++){                                        
        if(input.charAt(j) == word){                                        
          array[i] = input.substring(0, j);                                     
          input = input.substring(j + 1, input.length());                                       
          j=0;                                      
          i++;                                      
        }                                       
      }                                     
      return array;                                     
    }                                       
    return null;                                        
  }                                     
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                                                         
    String[] results = Test.intoArray("Test,putting,in,a,array");                                       
    for (String result : results)                                       
    {                                       
      System.out.println(result);                                       
    }                                                                           
  }                                     
}
```

I am trying to put string text into an array and displaying it downwards one by one as an array, but my output is Test,putting,in,a,array. Does this mean I have not put the string into an array?

Answer (score 1):

You currently are only getting one entry in your array because your words are separated by a comma, not a space. But, it's easy to fix change

```
char word = ' ';
```

to

```
char word = ',';
```

in `intoArray`. After that, I get (as I think you expected),

```
Test
putting
in
a
```

It is worth noting that in ***real*** code, `String.split(String)` is the right way to do it;

```
String[] results = "Test,putting,in,a,array".split(",");
```

Comment: Oh okay I understand, thank you. I see, I was trying to put them into a string without the usage of split